# Convert String column to DataTime

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my .net winform application i m importing excel data to SQL server. in my excel sheet i have 'STRT_TM' column containing dates in 03/01/2017 21:33:22 format. i want to do explicit conversion because in implicit conversion convert function is unable to determine whether the date is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.

In Sql Server i tried to convert a string to date. here is the code

```
select convert(smalldateTime,SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',7,4)+
SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',1,2) + SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',4,2))
```

the result is    **2017-03-01 00:00:00**
but when i try to include time part it gives error.
here is the code.

```
select convert(smalldateTime,SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',7,4)+ 
SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',1,2) + SUBSTRING('03/01/2017 14:05:34',4,2) + 
Substring('03/01/2017 14:05:34',12,8))
```

and error is

```
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a space between date and time:

```
select convert(smalldateTime,
Substring('03/01/2017 14:05:34',7,4) + 
Substring('03/01/2017 14:05:34',1,2) + 
Substring('03/01/2017 14:05:34',4,2) + ' ' +
Substring('03/01/2017 14:05:34',12,8))
```